# DataValidation Model / ViewModel / Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm designing a new website with ASP.NET MVC 4 (Beta), VS 11 (Beta), EF 5 (Beta), but this question suits for released versions of ASP.NET MVC 3, VS 2010, EF 4, too.

First step: I'm using Entity Framework Code First approach, for example, I've got following user model:

```
public class User
{
  [Key]
  public int UserId {get;set;}

  public String LoginName { get; set; }

  public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for registration I need another model, the registration model:

```
public class Registration
{
  public String LoginName { get; set; }

  public String Password { get; set; }

  public String PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

This is where my problems begin: Where should I put my DataValidation Annotations? For example the password should be at minimum 10 characters long and the PasswordConfirmed must match Password and so on. Do I have to write this on every model which could do something with the password (I'm thinking of having a ChangePassword model, too)

Another thing is how to deal with the controller. When I display my Registration ViewModel and everything is fine, do I create a User model and assign the variables from Registration ViewModel to it?

Sometimes I've a lot of properties which go to database, but not shown to the user (foreign keys, calculated values etc.).

As thinkink on DRY, I don't want to repeat my self.

What is the best practice for this one?

*To be clear: Annotations isn't a need. If there a better ways to validate, I will be glad, if you show them.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say objectively which is 'the best practice', but here's how I see it.
If you're binding to the view model, verify the view model, so:

```
public class Registration
{

    public String LoginName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=10)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=10)]
    public String PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

You can either do the validation 'by hand' in the controller, check on the `POST` if the password and confirmation matches, if not add an entry to the ModelState (but that may cause code repetition and is a bit cumbersome) OR use nice `IValidatableObject` interface on the model:

```
public class Registration : IValidatableObject
{

    public String LoginName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=10)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=10)]
    public String PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
        if(Password != PasswordConfirm)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Confirmation doesn't match", new[] {"PasswordConfirm"})
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Now with that, when you have your model bound after `POST`, the validation is done by simply calling `ModelState.IsValid`, and if it isn't valid, it returns the list of errors - including your custom errors.

Now of course you can put the DataAnnotations on the DB-model too as an additional measure, just 'in case' to avoid string truncation exceptions etc. if you somehow forgot and tried to push a longer string to the database anyway

As for the mapping, yes, after you have your model validated, at the end of the `POST` action you usually you map the properties from the model to either a new `User` instance (when adding to the DB) or to the existing one for update. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or write a naive mapper yourself using reflection - it's a relatively easy task, but it might be better to leave that as a stand-alone exercise, there is no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your entities only in domain layer. But when you need some DataValidation Annotations for your entity, you can use [MvcExtensions](http://mvcextensions.github.com/) for this. And if you have some composite or nested entities and you want to get them as a flatten objects, you should use [automapper](http://automapper.org/). This will be a best practice for you!

Comment: Well, i don't need Annotations. I can use other practices as well